# How to solve PHP For loop INF memory problem

Tags: php, for-loop, memory, methods

The problem with this code is that when the for loop is executing, the memory usage is increasing continuously. for example, when I run the code with a smaller `$seq_limit` 1000 it executes perfectly. but when the code is run with a `$seq_limit` value from 1500 it returns INF. What can I do to solve this problem? below is my code.

```
<?php

class fibonacci {

    private $seq_limit;
    private $sequence = array(1,2);
    private $even_values = array();
    private $sum_even;

    public function __construct(int $seq_limit){
    $this->seq_limit = $seq_limit;
    }
   
    public function fibonacci_sequence(){
       for ($i=0; $i<=$this->seq_limit-3; $i++) { 
        $this->sequence[] = $this->sequence[$i] + $this->sequence[$i+1];
       } 
       return $this->sequence;
    }

    public function even_values(){
        foreach ($this->fibonacci_sequence() as $value) {
            if ($value % 2 == 0) {
                $this->even_values[] = $value;
            }
        }
        return $this->even_values;
    }

    public function sum_even(){
        foreach ($this->even_values() as $value) {
            $this->sum_even += $value;
        }
        return $this->sum_even;
    }

 }


 $fibonacci = new fibonacci(1500);
 echo $fibonacci->sum_even();

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you implemented this in a way so as not to exhaust your memory, the 1500th fibbonacci number is `1.355E313`. That's a number with 314 digits. The largest representable double-precision floating point number is roughly `1.8E308`. If you want to go beyond that you're going to need to use a special library like BCmath to deal with numbers that large. It will not be fast.

That said, to generate a fibbonacci sequence the only thing you need to know is what the last two numbers were. Your memory is continuously increasing because you're continuously adding to it.

Alternatively, using a simple generator function:

```php
function fib_gen() {
    yield 1;
    yield 1;
    
    $state = [1,1];
    $offset=2;
    
    while(true) {
        $v = array_sum($state);
        yield $v;
        $state[$offset % 2] = $v;
        ++$offset;
    }
}

$c = 1;
$sum = 0;
$sum_even = 0;

$start = microtime(true);

foreach(fib_gen() as $f) {
    // printf("%4d: %d\n", $c, $f);
    $sum += $f;
    if( $c % 2 == 0 ) { $sum_even += $f; }
    if( $c++ >= 1000 ) { break; }
}

$end = microtime(true);

printf("     sum: %s\nsum_even: %s\nduration: %f ms\npeak mem: %d kB\n",
    $sum, $sum_even, ($end-$start)*1000, memory_get_peak_usage() / 1024
);
```

Output:

```
     sum: 1.1379692539836E+209
sum_even: 7.0330367711423E+208
duration: 1.071930 ms
peak mem: 416 kB
```